# CSS tab menu inside tab menu (tabs as images) Is this even possible?

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs

I can't figure out this problem, it is bugging me out!

I'm new to HTML CSS, but before I spend countless hours trying to get it to work can you tell me if this is even possible? I have no experience in js therefore I'm sticking to CSS and HTML only :)

Here is an image I created
[image: Example of my question]

Comment: SO you mean that you want to click on one of the 'project' links and show a new set of four images that are faded in?

Comment: Yeah, this is typical. Look at how to use unordered lists as menu wrappers <ul><li> (image, text) </li> ... </ul>

Also, take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Yes, inception. A tab menu inside a tab menu, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be whole lot easier to achieve with jquery.

But since you wanted to use only html css, Ill try to explain.

You can use ':hover' selector

eg

```
.button1:hover .children-images {
   background-image: url(./path-to-image);
}
```

That means, when user hover on '.button1', all .children-images will have new background image

But note that it only affects **CHILDREN** of the element that are hovered.

In other words,

```
<a class="button1">
   button text
   <div class="children-images button1-images">
      <img src="#"/>
       <img src="#"/>
      <img src="#"/>
   </div> 
</a>

<a class="button2">
button text
   <div class="children-images button2-images">
      <img src="#"/>
       <img src="#"/>
      <img src="#"/>
   </div> 
</a>
```

Given two buttons in html and css above, it will only affects '.children-images.button1-images'  not '.children-images.button2-images'

I hope it makes sense

And whether it can be achievable will depends on the visual element as well because your html structure will be quite limited.

So even if you can achieve the effect, you might be able to achieve other visual requirement of the site

Comment: Pleasure. However, using css to do all the effect you want is not ideal.  With the time and effort to do it, learn javascript / jquery liberary to do it. A lot easier to maintain your code and cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily using CSS only, except for the click in the case you don't want a page refresh. In that case you can only use a :hover for the project links. You can do it like this:

Here's how you'd do that in the case of a :hover without JavaScript:

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bL5x9/1/

First the HTML:

```
<h1>Projects</h1>
<ul id="main-list">
    <li class="main-item">
        <div>Project 1</div>
        <ul class="images">
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/sports/1"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/sports/2"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/sports/3"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/sports/4"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-item">
        <div>Project 2</div>
        <ul class="images">
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/city/1"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/city/2"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/city/3"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/city/4"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-item">
        <div>Project 3</div>
        <ul class="images">
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/abstract/1"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/abstract/2"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/abstract/3"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/abstract/4"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#main-list {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;  
  margin: 3px 0; 
  padding: 3px 0; 
  text-align: center;
}
li.main-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.images {
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
li:hover .images {
    opacity:1;
}
.images li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

The problem with this is that you'll need to keep hovering to see the images. Not sure if that is a problem.

In your case I'd just us one if the thousands of jQuery Menu plugins that are out there.